# AchartEngine (Hide Negative of X and Y Axis)

Tags: android, achartengine

I am using achartengine for my android application. How can I limit the x axis and y axis? I don't want the negative part of x axis and y axis to show up.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

U can disable the axis to move from place by using following method:

```
renderer.setPanEnabled(enable(boolean));
renderer.setPanEnabled(enabledX(boolean), enabledY(boolean));
```

If you want the axis should not go in negative values the you can use following method:

Here this method take array of double value with size =4;

```
renderer.setPanLimits(new double[]{{xMin, xMax, yMin,yMax});
```

Remember that you have to provide all 4 values compulsory else the pan will be disabled.
To get rid of max limit problem for both axis, I set Double.MAX_VALUE value as follows:

```
  renderer.setPanLimits(new double[]{0.0,Double.MAX_VALUE,0.0,Double.MAX_VALUE});
```

Answer (score 2):

I used following in my code .Hope this helps you.

```
 renderer.setXAxisMin(xMin);
 renderer.setXAxisMax(xMax);
 renderer.setYAxisMin(yMin);
 renderer.setYAxisMax(yMax);
```

And you can also make zoom and touch off by following snippet :

```
 renderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);
 renderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);
```

Comment: What is your value for xmin xmax ymin ymax? I try 0.0 as it should be a double. But the negative part still exist.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to hide negative(or positive) data you should use Limits.
use Limits like this:

```
Xmin=1;
Xmax=100;

Ymin=1;
Ymax=100;

double[] panLimits = {Xmin,Xmax, Ymin , Ymax};

multiRenderer.setPanLimits(panLimits);
```

with this code i hide negative values and lock chart pan on positive.

i hope this will be useful.